# IE Ajax Problem with non-ascii characters

Tags: java, jquery, internet-explorer, jsp, character-encoding

I have both sending and receiving jsp pages are encoded in UTF-8 jquery.post call works except IE. Page inputs are expected to be in Turkish  language. Turkish special characters çşığü messed up.

```
$.post('/answer.jsp', {cmd:'doSomething',nickname:nickNameUser}, 
 function(data){                
    if(data!=null && data.success){
        window.location.href="/main.htm";
    }
    else{
       $('#formError').text(data.error);    
    }                                       
 },
 'json');
```

What I have tried but failed

1-) I convert receiving jsp file to ISO-8859-9 and convert post to ajax provided charset

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',
    url:'/answer.jsp',
    data:{cmd:'doSomething', nickname:NickNameUser},
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=ISO-8859-9',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        if(data!=null && data.success){
            window.location.href="/main.htm";
        }
        else{
            $('#formError').text(data.error);
        }                                       
    }
});
```

2-) I tried on Java side following

```
nickname = new String(nickname.getBytes("utf-8"), "iso-8859-9");
```

None of them worked. Do you know any workaround?.
 By the way I hate IE.

Comment: In what way are the characters messed up, can you show? Are you 100% sure the Ajax response is UTF-8?

Comment: Characters turning to  :ÄÅÃ§kÄ±olÅÅÃ§iÄp

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
url=encodeURI(url);
```

and then put it as a param:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',
    url:url,.....
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment on the question:

> *Characters turning to: `ÄÅÃ§kÄ±olÅÅÃ§iÄp`*

That's what you get when you decode the character sequence `ğşçkıolşşçiğp` to bytes using UTF-8 and then encode those bytes to characters using ISO-8859-1 (or ISO-8859-9).

Modern browsers other than MSIE are smart enough to detect the response encoding when the charset is not specified in the HTTP `Content-Type` header of the response of the page returning the initial HTML. Thus, that it fails on MSIE can only mean that the proper charset is not been specified in the HTTP `Content-Type` header.

Adding the following line to very top of JSP page which is rendering the HTML code should fix it:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

It will set the response encoding and the content type header charset to the specified charset.

You can also add the following entry to your webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file to let it take effect on every JSP page of your webapp:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

---

Perhaps you're already doing it the right way, but you should also take into account that you're parsing the POST request parameters using the same charset. In the `answer.jsp` which you (ab)used as a JSON service, you should ensure that the following line is called before you access any request parameter:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String nickname = request.getParameter("nickname");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)